# On Android Studio, the inspection "Unused resources" doesn't work for all modules on my project

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, android-lint

I run it this way "Menu -> Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name -> Unused resources" and I select entire project but it doesn't find any unused resources outside my main App Module. So I then run it for individual modules and it finds stuff but it also finds items that are used on other modules.

For example, I have a shared module which has some common strings in it, like "dismiss" for dialogs. The string is not used in that module. When I run the inspection just for that module it finds it as unused.

On the other hand, I have some string on that same shared module that I no longer use anywhere, and when I run the inspections for the entire project, it won't find that string.

I think the issue might be the way I did shared modules, basically they are on different directories I import them putting this on settings.gradle:

```
include ':androidutils'
project(':androidutils').projectDir = new File( '../sharedlibs/androidutils')
```

Then in my build.gradle I just import `:androidutils` as a dependency.

Anyone else have this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue when I upgrade from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0. 

What Gradle version and Android Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm still on 2.3 and just did this yesterday and still had this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with Android Studio 3.0 - did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Lint finding unused strings is broken now for me as well. I have several dozen I know are unused, but Lint can't detect them anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click to Module and you will see that.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).